# set google column chart height with google map

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I have to set the google column chart height with google map. displaying the graph as per human ratios. i could differentiate the men and women category. but the population wise have to vary the height of chart.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
[ '村名', '男性',{ role: "style" }, '女性', { role: "style" } ],  
[関本村,3,2],
[下長竹村,152,70],
[中里村,30,35],
[永塚村,3,2],
[落幡村,7,1],
[関本村,3,2],
]);
var options = {
        width:300,
        height:200,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        colors: ['#58ACFA','#FFC0CB'],
        legend: {position: 'none', textStyle: {color: 'white', fontSize: 12}},
        bar: { groupWidth: '5%' },
        baselineColor: 'transparent',
        vAxis: { gridlines: { count: 0, color: 'transparent' }, },
        hAxis: { textPosition: 'bottom',textStyle: {color: 'white', fontSize: 15}},
        isStacked: true,
  };
```

height:200 is displaying the chart height as same.

[image]

have to display different height of each graph.. any idea ??

Comment: it would be easier to provide an answer with a working example of what you have now, at least some sample data -- but seems to me the height could be calculated from the data for all charts -- prior to drawing them...

Comment: question edited with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to calculate the relative size based on the population of each row.

You can use a weighted average, then multiply that by some total size of all charts.

Here, I use 500. However, you'll notice a large disparity between the min and max populations. Not sure how well a chart would turn out, 8 pixels tall...

You could possibly use some sort of multiplier to bring them closer. Just wanted to demonstrate a possibility...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});

function drawChart() {
  var popSize;
  var sizeArray = [];
  var showResult;
  var tempDiv;
  var totalSize = 500;
  var total = 0;

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['??', '??','??'],
    ['???',3,2],
    ['????',152,70],
    ['???',30,35],
    ['???',3,2],
    ['???',7,1],
    ['???',3,2],
  ]);


  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    popSize = data.getValue(i, 1) + data.getValue(i, 2);
    sizeArray.push(popSize);
    total += popSize;
  }

  showResult = document.getElementById('displaySizes');
  for (var i = 0; i < sizeArray.length; i++) {
    sizeArray[i] = (sizeArray[i] / total) * totalSize;
                                                   
    // example purposes only
    tempDiv = showResult.appendChild(document.createElement('DIV'));
    tempDiv.innerHTML = sizeArray[i].toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="displaySizes"></div>
```

then use `sizeArray` in your options...

```
var options = {
  width: 300,
  height: sizeArray[i],
  ...
```